# How do I remove the period when the answer is outputted?

Tags: c#

The problem is, using a while loop, create a program which will have the user enter a series of words until they enter a period (“.”). Your program should output the sentence which was created by concatenating all of the words together excluding the period.

Sample input:

I
LOVE
COMPUTER
SCIENCE
.

Sample Output:  I LOVE COMPUTER SCIENCE

I've tried to find other sources for help without finding much. This is what I have tried so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter some words:\n");
        string word = Console.ReadLine();
        string period = Console.ReadLine();
        while (period!=".")
        {
            word = Console.ReadLine();
            if (period==".")
            {
                Console.Write(word);
                break;
            }
            else
                continue;
        }
        Console.Write(word);
```

Comment: Remove the `Console.Write(word);` line from the `if` body

Comment: Not sure why you have both `word` and `period`. `period` is only set once so will loop forever or not at all.

Comment: Create a `List<string>` and add each entry that is not a `.` to it.  After the loop, output the entries with `String.Join()`.

Comment: You're reading an entire line at a time, and have two reads.  This won't work because you could end up reading the word with the period in the first readline.  You need a single readline in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0), [String.TrimEnd()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-5.0), [String.EndsWith()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.endswith?view=net-5.0), and [String.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> words = new List<string>();

    Console.WriteLine("Type one word at at time, each followed by Enter.");
    Console.WriteLine("A word ending with a period, '.', will stop word entries.");

    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {
        String word = Console.ReadLine();  
        words.Add(word.TrimEnd('.'));
        quit = word.EndsWith(".");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", words));

    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
Type one word at at time, each followed by Enter.
A word ending with a period, '.', will stop word entries.
I
LOVE
COMPUTER
SCIENCE.
I LOVE COMPUTER SCIENCE
Press Enter to Quit
```

Comment: this will work, however the instructions he was given say to have the period on a new line.  That would simplify your answer.

Comment: @JohnLord Yeah, that aspect was unclear to me.  The instructions don't actually say if the period is on a new line or not; it just says `until they enter a period (“.”)`. The SAMPLE INPUT given by the user does have it at the end of the word....but then their code kind of implies that it should be on its own line, but the logic is sketchy so it's hard to know what the actual scenario should be.  ***insert shoulder shrug here***

Answer (score 0):

```cs
Console.Write("Enter some words:\n");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
do {
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    sb.Append(line);
    sb.Append(" ");
} while (!line.EndsWith("."));
string result = sb.ToString()[0..^3] // don't include the last two characted
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace SampleProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter some words");

            string newWord = "";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while(newWord != ".") //If the user inputs a period, the program will continue with the code outside this loop
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a word: ");
                newWord = Console.ReadLine();
                sb.Append(newWord+" "); //Add the word entered by the user to the other words
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); //Write a string containing all the entered words
            Console.Read(); //Prevent the program to end abruptly
        }
    }
}
```